Cuba 2003 Coloring Problem
A $4 \times 4$ board has all of its squares painted white. The only allowed operation is to choose a rectangle that contains $3$ squares and paint each of the boxes as follows:
a) If the box is white, then it is painted black.
b) If the box is black, then it is painted white.
Prove that by applying the allowed operation several times, it is impossible to get the entire board painted black.
It is a coloring problem, so I've checked coloring the chessboard with strominos covering the $3\times1$ rectangles. However, there can be repetition. I think the best option left here is checking some invariants, which I have done in $\mod 2,3,5,7,9$, but nothing came out of there; a small hint will be enough to solve the problem, in my opinion.

Our grid is $E=\{(x,y), 1 \le x \le 4 , 1 \le y \le 4 \}$
We can consider 3 subsets :
For $i=0,1,2$, $E_i = \{(x,y) , (x+y)\%3=i \}$
$E_0$ and $E_1$ contain $5$ cells, $E_2$ contains $6$ cells. Each rectangle $1 \times 3$ contains exactly $1$ cell of each subset.
We can consider $n_i =$ number of cells of subset $E_i$ that are white.
Our objective is to have $n_0=n_1=n_2=0$, so, particularly, we want to have $n_1$ and $n_2$ same parity.
At the beginning, $n_1$ and $n_2$ are not same parity. At each move, $n_0$ , $n_1$ and $n_2$ change $(+1$ or $-1)$, so parity of $n_0$, $n_1$ and $n_2$ all change. So it is impossible to have $n_1$ and $n_2$ same parity.
